# Turn a string into an array, separated by double quotes and commas (",") in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

So I have this string in php

```
string(32) => ""CU-00116","CU-00054","CU-00087""
```

the double quotes are included, I want to implode them to become an array

```
["CU-00116","CU-00054","CU-00087"]
```

I'm using implode like this,

```
$arr[] = implode('","', $myStr);
```

it says `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: What you want ? You want to convert this string into array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reverse of implode:

```
$arr = explode('","', trim($string, '"'));
```

`implode()` is used to convert an array into a string, `explode()` converts a string into an array. `trim()` is used to remove the quotes from the beginning and end.

Comment: An explanation of the `trim()` usage would be nice to help people understand your solution better.

Answer (score 1):

`implode` use to convert array to string.

Your given string is not a valid string.
it should be like `'"CU-00116","CU-00054","CU-00087"'`

if just want to convert this string into the array, then you just need to define array like.

array('"CU-00116","CU-00054","CU-00087"');

or If you need to convert every value with separate index then you need to explode this string like this,

```
explode(",",$yourString);
```

Try this.

```
$yourStr  =  '"CU-00116","CU-00054","CU-00087"';

$a        =  array($yourStr);

print_r($a);


$b        =  explode(",",$yourStr);

print_r($b);
```

Comment: Please edit your response to fix spelling mistakes in the function names at the very least.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 $string= '"CU-00116","CU-00054","CU-00087"';
 $arr= preg_split("/[,]/",$string);
```

Comment: 1) It does not answer the question completely - the quotes around codes need to be removed too; 2) using regexp instead of a simple `explode()` is certainly an overkill and gives you a performance penalty; 3) Your answer only gives code but does not explain what/how/why it is doing, so it does not help to learn something new - it's clear only if you know this

Comment: @mkilmanas alright. Lesson learned. Every answer without an explanation deserves a downvote.